# Will Time Machine recognize old files after a clean reinstall of macos?

Tags: backup, time-machine, install

I am about to fully wipe and reinstall macos.  However, on my Time Machine backup disk there is not a lot of space left and I am wondering, when I set up Time Machine again after the reinstall, will it redo a full backup or will it recognize files that are already backed up?

Computer name will remain the same.
The home folder structure will also be mostly as it is now.
But I will *not* "restore from TM backup" and instead manually put everything in my home folder back into place.  The question is if it will require the full size of the backup again (and therefore delete old backups)?